# KeyCloak as IDP to Salesforce SP - SP initiated SSO not working

Tags: keycloak, saml

I am new to KeyCloak, and am trying to configure it as a SAML IDP to a SalesForce client.
IDP initiated SSO flow works fine. I am directed to the Salesforce home page correctly post-authentication. However, SP initiated SSO gives me a JSON output instead of the Keycloak login page.

This is the URL that SalesForce is redirecting to (masked IP):
http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test?SAMLRequest=...
SAML tracer indicates a valid SAML authentication request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://f-corpcont--dev.my.salesforce.com?so=00D3K000000lOS"
                    Destination="http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test"
                    ID="_2CAAAAXJxZQlkME8wswMDAwMDAwMDA2AAAA3kJle3T1o4lEOE9QztKYIVXwLjlHOcfEaw-7mLWvYqmEiPv5SS32lT0WcQIbjXTP-qO779xPjACwqlhiGs9ZM8ZmltHZd6stzimY1Br3b1_5PqBgWxExV7R1FAAxZ914_3s8rViWWGxmKKGFN94OG2WBh3SMPF3WwGagDIZLRKtSpcGIDCGkuYERb_DR0LgOflx-C0kF7XqKdtU8OTTbk0HpoCKQ8oRh58Mai1eFlqgKf50rdGsFQmCQa-Sg0-JyZg"
                    IssueInstant="2020-05-04T19:39:22.807Z"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    Version="2.0">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://f-corpcont--dev.my.salesforce.com</saml:Issuer>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

The JSON output I see in my browser is:

```
{
    "realm": "test",
    "public_key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqHobhU5mQ2itvVfkDWm64sLgT9dfoCNm137ul+A7YRNSXk5g0JEGxoZLVdicRQUx0mr4z6BEM+LN/mztSsigG0aQIqUY8y1un33kBk5gE6W3jaFDX6Rsap/lcXIoO7Jl/pzjAxf3R8RyMMhFQ4Hi1rHl2wSXMWfeNLaoLrzy+LEG1KNZpfhbfG1HUa5fEYpI0sSWEEgcP3faEy2JWOJrfJrcS1tezDD+7x4u+fTUJt0M8vsIjMDAX9UUu+JXnG901a15drj9UjYJyiMJTFQt3Rdrxv96XZa93fKyB36an5GDZWPiwEehtjAJ4mQ0oo0v/TmevoJwZd7YTvClQIDAQAB",
    "token-service": "http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect",
    "account-service": "http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test/account",
    "tokens-not-before": 0
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used wrong URL for SAML request. Wrong:

```
http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test?SAMLRequest=
```

Correct:

```
http://10.99.xxx.xxx:8080/auth/realms/test/protocol/saml?SAMLRequest=
```

Comment: That is the URL where the vendor/service provider is being directed when they send an authentication request. That URL came from the keycloak metadata. In any case, I did already try changing it to /protocol/saml but I get a message saying Invalid Request

Comment: @crimson_sails as you see you are not reading SAML IDP metadata correctly: it isn't entityID property, but SingleSignOnService (and then correct binding method of course) property in the SAML IDP metadata provided by Keycloak. And as you see it is working - Keycloak is processing your SAML request. Check Keycloak logs to get more details why your SAML request it invalid.

Comment: I just checked back with the SalesForce team and found an error with their configuration of the keycloak IDP metadata. They changed the URL to include the /protocol/saml and it does work now. Thank you for your assistance.